# What does the "Interoperability IFD" EXIF tag mean, and how can it be different for the same image?

Tags: image, photo, exif

I am hunting for duplicates in my photo albums, and I stumbled upon some image pairs for which (seemingly) all visual data is the same, all EXIF tags are the same, except this "Interoperability IFD" field. For one image pair I checked it is 4896 and 4908 for the two files.

I'm pretty sure it is the same photo taken, it was just imported twice in different time/ways. What does this tag mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is a byte offset into the Interoperability IFD "table". EXIF can contain several "tables" (list of "IDs" and "values"). Some table items are not actual data, but references to further "tables" (e.g. 0x8769 ExifTag, 0x8825 GPSTag or 0xA005 IopTag). This offset can of course vary depending in which order an implementer chooses to save the exif information and its different "tables".

Since your software seems to simply output this value, it might be safe to assume that it does not follow this offset to read the additional tags inside the Interoperability IFD "table" (tags 0x0001-0x0002 and 0x1000-0x1002).

Source https://www.exiv2.org/tags.html